window.open from a https to http, and from https to http
first of all, this is really important for my website, I need to open a specific http page
I want to know if its a good practice to use window.open to open a page with different protocol (like http -> https | https -> http)
It works in my computer, but I'm not sure if it works with other browsers and OSes.
ChatGPT told me that this is not allowed but I can't see someone on the internet saying that this is not allowed.

You can link to wherever and whatever you like you using any protocol at any time, so in that sense ChatGPT is wrong - and not for the first time. However, if you need to retain cookies or auth data for example, then that will be lost as the URI must match, down to the port and protocol, for them to be readable. It would perhaps be a better question if you could describe the goal you're actually trying to reach instead of a vague question about theoretical functionality.

its ok i dont care about localStorage sessionStorage or cookies

It would be useful to know why you can't get the site with http to use https

@mplungjan good question, the thing is that my page connects to a ws (not wss) server in my user's pc, and this is not allowed via https

And why can't they make a WSS server? They can use a self signed cert if the user will allow the cert to load

@mplungjan yeah, i through that, seems like chrome is not allowing self signed cert
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312311/secure-websockets-with-self-signed-certificate

@WORMHACKER To allow self-signed certificates to be used, start Chrome with the --ignore-certificate-errors flag, e,g:
chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever --ignore-certificate-errors

HTTP and HTTPS are protocol standards independent of OS, whatever works on Windows should work on other platform.
Back to your question, you can pretty much redirect http traffic to https but not recommended the other way round. I am not sure there is any incentive to moving from secured protocol (https) to non-secured protocol (http).

it might not depend of the OS, but it can depend on the browser, i want to know if it's a safe standard to do this specifically (like, if browsers will allow it and its not considered hacky)
just to be somewhat sure it will be not changed in the future
